# Using Braintree on Meteor mobile (android - cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, digital-ocean, braintree

I am using Meteor 1.3 with android platform and [patrickml:braintree@1.32.0](https://github.com/patrickml/braintree) to be able to process in-app payments.

I configured braintree and inserted a Drop-in UI, which is the simplest way to do it.

While testing, if I run it on web (localhost) or with `meteor run android-device` with no mobile-server configuration, then the drop in UI is shown on the device.

However, when I try to integrate everything on my hosted server in Digital Ocean and try to test it using:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server=http://example.com
```

the drop in UI just does not show.

Does it have something to do with the lac of SSL security on my domain?

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work. Just have to be sure to connect through HTTPS on the mobile server and braintree can provide iFrame through secure connection.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact our [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

Braintree.js [does not support compile-to-native runtimes](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/browser-support#webviews) such as Cordova.

Comment: Why? This is the future.

Comment: Yes - why ? how should we integrate paypal in app then ?