# Cordova braintree plugin

Tags: cordova, braintree

I am trying to integrate "braintree" payment plugin into my cordova application. I am able to initialize the braintree plugin successfully. But i am not able to get the UI of the payment page.

```
// Initializing... this is working fine

var token = "xxcssf...";

BraintreePlugin.initialize(token,
    function () { console.log("init OK!"); },
    function (error) { console.error(error); 
});     

// Calling the payment method... not able to execute this code... not getting issues too

var options = {
    amount: "49.99",
    primaryDescription: "Your Item"
};

BraintreePlugin.presentDropInPaymentUI(options, function (result) {
    if (result.userCancelled) {
        console.debug("User cancelled payment dialog.");
    } else {
        console.info("User completed payment dialog.");
        console.info("Payment Nonce: " + result.nonce);
        console.debug("Payment Result.", result);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Considering that [Braintree does not support compile-to-native frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36986655/5326365), you may have better luck reaching out to the developer of the plugin. Furthermore, it would be extremely helpful if you'd update your question with a specific error or some logging when calling the `#presentDropInPaymentUI`.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me this way:

1. Put this inside the head tag:

   ```
   <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.4.0/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. add this tag, just ending the body tag:

   ```
   <div id="payment-form"></div>
   ```
3. Call braintreeService and $window in your controller.

Now all should work.

Good Luck !